# ffplay seek when pts big than 26.5hour

Tags: c, ffmpeg, seek

I use ffmepg record rtsp stream to Ts file, but pts maxsize is 33bit(26.5hours,95443second).

When I record more than `26.5` hours, pts will restart from `0`. the ffplay can not seek more than `26.5` hours timestamp.

How to change the ffplay to support it?

maybe i asked vaguely, the particulars is i save a rtsp stream to ts file by ffmpeg per 10 second , it may last for a long time(more than 26.5hour), when it done, it will save a m3u8 file, after that, i use ffplay to play then m3u8 file, if i want to seek to 26.7hour , the play must be stoped. -----PTS (sec) = 8589934592 / 90 000 Hz = 95443,7 seconds (26,5 hours)

Comment: Not a programming question - try [su] ?

Comment: @PaulR not sure I can agree, sounds like OP wants to fix FFMPEG's source code.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: you may be right, but the question is very vague and doesn't really specify what they want to do and/or how they want to achieve it.

Comment: hallo hansonzou, can you specify where the `pts` you're referring is? is it part of FFMPEG's source code? can you link to a file?

Comment: use a different format or fragment your record

Comment: maybe i asked vaguely, the particulars is i save a rtsp stream to ts file by ffmpeg per 10 second , it may last for a long time(more than 26.5hour), when it done, it will save a m3u8 file, after that, i use ffplay to play then m3u8 file, if i want to seek to 26.7hour , the play must be stoped. -----PTS (sec) = 8589934592 / 90 000 Hz = 95443,7 seconds (26,5 hours)